# How to copy an xml tag and its value into another xml file under the same root tag

Tags: text-processing, xml

I need to copy an xml tag and its value to another xml file under same root tag. Create the root tag if it doesn't exist.

Here is an input output example.

```
INPUT: string.xml
<resource>
    <string name="app_name">MyExampleApp</string>
    <string name="profile">My Profile</string>
    <string name="messages">My Messages</string>
</resource>

$ command "profile" string.xml string1.xml

OUTPUT: string1.xml
<resource>
    <string name="profile">My Profile</string>
</resource>
```

I was looking for that "Command" and options. Not necessarily in that order. Please help me out here. Any Linux/Unix/Mac command will do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/), you could *delete* all the `string` nodes under the root node whose `name` attribute is not `profile`:

```
$ xml ed -d '/resource/string[@name != "profile"]' string.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<resource>
  <string name="profile">My Profile</string>
</resource>
```

Add `-O` after `ed` if you don't want the XML declaration line.

Comment: I think `-t` is not needed here (it's an option for `sel`, not `ed`).

Comment: @SatoKatsura You're right, `xml` silently ignores it. I'll amend the answer.

Comment: `xml ed -t` segfaults here...

Comment: @SatoKatsura Oopsie. What's the system and where did you get XMLStarlet from? I'm on OS X with XMLStarlet from NetBSD's pkgsrc.

Comment: OpenBSD (from ports) and Linux (compiled from sources).

Comment: @SatoKatsura On OpenBSD (pre-6.0) I do actually get a "Warning: unrecognized option '-t'" error... But never mind, the option is not supposed to be there anyway. I've fixed it in the answer.